# chdir warning when opening  .tar file on OS X

Tags: macos, tar

I need to unarchive a file to the `/Developer` folder.

> Install Qt for iOS SDK
>
> The Qt for iOS SDK has been configured to be
>   installed in the default Xcode installation location /Developer. It is
>   not possible to install the SDK into another location without first
>   rebuilding it, as the install location is contained within the qmake
>   executable, and that is built as part of Qt.
>
> To install the Qt for iOS
>   SDK, open ‘Terminal’ and type the following from the command­‐line:
>
> ```
> tar –xf qt­‐everywhere-­ios­‐4.8.0­‐xxx.tar.gz –C /Developer
> ```
>
> (where xxx is an identifier which can be used to determine the build
>   of the iOS SDK eg. arm7-­‐nossl) This will install the Qt for iOS SDK
>   into the following path:
>
> ```
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/share/qt­‐everywhere­‐ios­‐4.8.0
> ```

When I perform the operation I get the information:

```
Lions-Mac:Documents User$ tar -xf qt-everywhere-ios-4.8.0-arm7-nossl.tar.gz -C /Developer 
tar: could not chdir to '/Developer'
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: `tar -C /Developer -xvvvf qt-everywhere-ios-4.8.0-arm7-nossl.tar` — does that add any details? Can you open the file by double-clicking it?

Comment: yes I can open it by double-clicking. But I need to do it according text in EDIT

Comment: Have you considered that the file is broken due to e.g. aborted download, or transmission errors?

Comment: One command says `.tar`, the other `.tar.gz`. Are you actually using the correct file name?

Comment: I think the file is correct because I can double click it and unarchive it, but I want to do it as they said in the text above. I have tried '.tar' and '.tar.gz' and the same thing is happening

Comment: What's the output of `file qt­‐everywhere-­ios­‐4.8.0­‐xxx.tar.gz` on the command line when run from the same directory as the tar command?

Comment: Does /Developer exist? I think it was replaced in recent Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** In Xcode 4.3 or higher the `/Developer` folder is not used. You do not need to, or actually should not extract anything there!

If `tar` is missing permissions to write there, use the same command, but prefixed with `sudo`.

```
sudo tar -xf qt-everywhere-ios-4.8.0-arm7-nossl.tar.gz -C /Developer
```

This will perform the command with `root` permissions.

Comment: You'll also get the same error if /Developer doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *gzipped* `tar` file (see the `.gz` extension), so you need to add `z`.

```
tar -xzf qt-everywhere-ios-4.8.0-arm7-nossl.tar.gz -C /Developer
```

Comment: I have tried it and the same thing is happening

Comment: I have put more details in the EDIT if that even helps

Comment: @denonth Where did you get that information from, though? Can you add a link or so?

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.mediator-software.com/

Comment: See the updated question – your answer might be obsolete now.